# Lambdas not working with function accepting std::function

Tags: c++

Why does not this work with lambdas? It only works when I assing lambda to std::function before calling the function I want. Doesn't work when I construct lambda in place or assign lambda to auto.

```
#include <functional>

template <typename R>
R foo (std::function<R()> fun)
{
    puts(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
int main()
{
    std::function<int()> lambda = []{ return 1; };
    foo (lambda); // --> OK

    foo ([]() -> int { return 1; } ); // --> ERROR

    auto lambda2 = []{ return 1; };
    foo (lambda2); // --> ERROR
}
```

Comment: You should *really* return something from your `foo` function. Not returning anything, like you do in your MCVE, leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: And do you *need* the function argument to be a `std::function` object? Can't it simply be a template? Like e.g. `template<typename F> auto foo(F fun) -> decltype(fun()) { ... }`.

Comment: No, because I need to take the return type the lambda returns. As far as I know there is not trait for this.

Comment: That's what the `decltype(fun())` thing does. It gets the return type of `fun` no matter if it's a lambda, a pointer to a function, or any other callable object.

Comment: You are right. That was what I was searching for. You solved my problem. Thank you :-)

Comment: As a matter of fact I tried this approach earlier, with decltype, but I made an error and wrote "decltype(fun)" instead of "decltype(fun())"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add template parameter to `foo`:

```
foo<int> ([]() -> int { return 1; } ); // --> OK
foo<int> (lambda2); // --> OK
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `<R>` is not deducible from the lambda. In fact, there are many types `R` such that `std::function` can hold your lambda.

When the argument provided is `std::function<int()>`, `R` can trivially be deduced as `int()`. But lambda's have their own unique type. It's not `std::function`.